# Why does one column shrink to content size when another exceeds the browser height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout comprised of a css table so that the content area will "fill" the space below the header.

The content area also has a side navigation menu.  The HTML looks something like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="layout-table" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="layout-row">
        There's a Header in here!
    </div>
    <div class="layout-row" style="height: 100%;">
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="height: 100%;">
            Side Navigation Here!
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10" style="height: 100%;">
            Main Content!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.layout-table{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.layout-row{
    display: table-row;
}
.layout-row .col-md-12{
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

I put the `height: 100%;`s in there so you can see where I have them.

On pages where the "Main Content!" section does not extend past the length of the browser window (no scrollbar displayed), the `col-sm-2` side navigation bar is full height just like the main content area.  However, any time the Main Content area is larger than the browser window can hold, the side navigation menu snaps up (shrinks) to the size of its content instead of the full height of the Main Content div.

I've checked when this happens and all of the elements have `height: 100%;` even in the inspector after it has shrunk.  I'm guessing that it either has something to do with columns in Bootstrap, or the use of `display: table`, or some interaction between the two maybe?

What I want to happen is that the side navigation menu should be the full height of the Main Content div, even when that div is larger than the browser window.

**EDIT**

Here's a bootply of the issue:

http://www.bootply.com/6PbNVj71Hs#

It won't save with `<html>` and `<body>` tags in there, so you'll have to add them in with `style="height: 100%;"` if you want to delete the extra content to see what it looks like when it's working normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `min-height: 100%;` attribute to your stylesheet to prevent it from shrinking.

Comment: No dice, still does it.  I edited in a bootply of the issue if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

When you set a height of 100%, what you're telling the element to do is to take up 100% of the available height in the parent element.  Since all of your elements have height: 100%, each element will only take up 100% of the space necessary for the content within to display, so the height becomes content-driven instead of container-driven.

So, what you might want to try is to give a set height to the parent element that you want to use to drive container heights of its children.  In your case, I believe that's the div element ".layout-row".  You could always set a height for the body element too, then you can set percentage heights for all descendent elements so that your page is responsive.  Something like this:

```
body {
    height: 100vh; /* vh = viewport height, which is the height of your screen */
}
```

or

```
.layout-row:nth-of-type(2) {
     height: 300px;
}
```

By the way, since you're using Bootstrap columns, why not use Bootstrap rows also?  All you would have to do is replace the class "layout-row" with "row", which is a Bootstrap class.  Using both row and column classes means that the document will respond to a grid, which means you won't need to force display: table in your CSS.  You can see a great explanation of Bootstrap CSS [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/).

Hope that helps!

Comment: But when I look at the `<html>` element it's height is the full height of the browser, as is the `<body>` and the `class='layout-row'`.  All the way down to the `col-sm-2`, whose parent's height is the full screen, and has its own height set to 100%, but it doesn't fill the parent height.

Comment: @Tevis - when you say "the height is the full height of the browser", what does that mean?  Is the height attribute 100%?  Without setting a fixed height for a parent element, 100% or auto heights will be content-driven.